# Footnote appears in next page at the end of chapter

Tags: page-breaking

i dont have a code for this, but the question should be clear. What do you do when the rest of your footnoote (very long one) appears in the last empty page of a chapter. How do you push some text to that page ?

Comment: put `\pagebreak` at the point that you want the pagebreak (or better write some more words to reach the last page:-)

Comment: I'd love to but it's not my text. Actually the problem is worse than i thought, the footnote is at the end of the chapter, last word.

Comment: hard to say without the text, you can force a pagebreak with `\pagebreak`  or perhaps better you can use `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` on one or more pages in the chapter to shorten the pages and perhaps force the text carrying the footnote on to the last page or ...

Comment: It's missing 16 lines to do that. I'll try and see at the end, playing with text size etc, but I have two of these monsters. Thanks

Comment: Actually \enlargethispage{-\baselineskip} seems to work, I used it about 16 times

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you add an answer, including the command to do the opposite (push the text forward) and a short description of what the commands do visually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae,
arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non,
nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus,
magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas
dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{\blindtext}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in,
fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio\footnotemark.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which do you think would be better, messing with the page or put it earlier ?

Comment: Personally, I'd pad the next to last page with clip art.